# Strange Text Issue in UILabel of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

I have a UILabel in a HeaderView of a UICollectionView. The text of the label is displayed, but there is some very strange formatting issue. The edges of all of the lines are very jagged, and it looks very bad. [image]

Anyone know a solution to this? I have never seen this problem before. My code for the custom view is below:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    var reusableView = UICollectionReusableView();

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24.0)
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            label.text = "UILabel with Weird Text Issues"
        default:
            label.text = ""
        }
        label.sizeToFit()
        let leftInset = self.cv.contentInset.left
        label.frame = CGRectMake(leftInset , header.frame.height-label.frame.height, label.frame.width, label.frame.height)
        header.addSubview(label)
        reusableView = header
    }

    return reusableView
}
```

Comment: Is this on a real device or the simulator? Sometimes things simply don't scale correctly on the simulator resulting in jagged lines or a few missing pixels.

Comment: That is a screenshot from a real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your `Label` many times, your problem is that, you need to remove your `UILabel` before add new one,

something like

```
    for view in header.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

I hope this helps you